# Complex grid with smooth performance

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net-4.5, telerik-grid

My website is built in ASP.NET 4.5 and in one of the pages I have to display data in tabular format(grid). Where I also to allow the user to perform some complex operations. 
Also the data populated in grid is coming from different sources. Because of which the fetching and binding of data is also becoming time consuming.
Can anybody please suggest what would the best option in this case?
I have tried using gridview but it is a very heavy control to be used in such scenario.

Thanks in advance.